# How to change originalFilename of MultipartFile

Tags: java, multipartform-data

I have a MultipartFile file on server side. I would like to change the original file name of this file, yet the class only support getOriginalFilename().

Can anyone help me with this? PS: It is an image file uploaded.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Do you want to give a new name of the upload file and save it?

Comment: You can't change original name of `MultipleFile`. But you can save this file with another name, when will pass `File` to `transferTo()` method.

Answer (score 8):

You can change the name with MockMultipartFile class. 
For example, to add a timestamp to multipart file.

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = new  MockMultipartFile(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(oldMultipartFile.getOriginalFilename()).concat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(new Date())) + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(oldMultipartFile.getOriginalFilename()), oldMultipartFile.getInputStream());
```

and then use multipartFile with new name 
or you can just rename file before save like this

```
  String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(new Date());

  file.getOriginalFilename().replace(file.getOriginalFilename(), FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getOriginalFilename()).concat(currentDate) + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename())).toLowerCase())
```

Comment: The second answer is incorrect. We cannot directly replace the original name like that. We need to store the replaced result in a variable.

Comment: thanx bro. Your answer is very helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new MultipartFile instance by updating its

> originalFileName

with new one other files with the same existing file fields.

Just call following method as

> getNewFile("newFileName", currentFile)

current file is the MultipartFile object of the existing file.

```
private MultipartFile getNewFile(String fileName, MultipartFile currentFile){
        return new MultipartFile() {
            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return currentFile.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public String getOriginalFilename() {
                return fileName;
            }

            @Override
            public String getContentType() {
                return currentFile.getContentType();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return currentFile.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public long getSize() {
                return currentFile.getSize();
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
                return currentFile.getBytes();
            }

            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                return currentFile.getInputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public void transferTo(File file) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {

            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
//this will provide the complete filename, let "file.txt";
        File fileSaved = fileRepository.save(new File());
//let's save that on a repo, not file, just some reference, easy to handle
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 4) + fileSaved.getFileId() + fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 4);
//change the file name a bit, just put the id from the repo, it will be unique by default, right ? and what's that 4 - ".txt" has 4 alphabets, currently i neeed to handle only txt, so I hard-coded this
        Path targetLocation = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName);
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
//it will be never replaced, even filenames are same,id will be unique
}
```